# Prove $\ \mathbf C $ is basis of $\ \mathbb R^n$ if $\ \mathbf C^\bot = \{0\} $

Tags: linear-algebra

if $\ \mathbf C = \{v_1,v_2,\dots ,v_n \} $ is a subset of $\ \mathbb R^n$ and the $\ \mathbf C^\bot = \{ 0 \} $ then  $\ \mathbf C $ is a base of $\ \mathbb R^n$ .

I was thinking since any subspace $\ C  $ of $\ \mathbb R^n = C \oplus C^\bot $ and since  $\ \dim (\mathbf C^\bot) = 0 $ and $\ \mathbf C^\bot \cap \mathbf C = \{0\}  $ then $\ \dim (\mathbb R^n) = \dim(\mathbf C) + \dim(\mathbf C^\bot) $ and therefore $\ \dim(\mathbb R^n) = \dim( \mathbf C ) $

The answer I saw in the book is different so I'm not sure about this?

Comment: There is no finite non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$ wrt to the usual addition. You want $C$ to be a *subset* of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: correct! It is about subset!

Comment: Your answer is correct, with $\mathbf C$ standing for the span of the given vectors, not the set itself, but it may be assuming a very strong fact compared to your textbook. You can summarize what your textbook has done in a few lines : we will try to clarify it.

Comment: Suppose $\ C^\bot = \{ 0 \} $ then $\ C^{\bot\bot} = Sp(C) \Rightarrow Sp(C) = C^{\bot\bot} = \{ 0 \}^\bot = \mathbf R^n \Rightarrow $ C is a spreading group of $\ \mathbf R^n $ with $\ n $ vectors hence it is a basis of $\ \mathbf R^n $. also $\ C^{\bot\bot} = Sp(C) $\ because $\ C^\bot = Sp(C)^\bot \rightarrow C^{\bot\bot} = Sp(C)^{\bot\bot} $ but $\ Sp(C)^{\bot\bot} = Sp(C) $

Comment: by the way , the fact you mean I'm assuming is $\ R^n = C \oplus C $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $C$ only has $n$ vectors and $\operatorname{span} C=\mathbb R^n$, $C$ is a basis.

For suppose $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are not linearly independent.   Then $\exists\vec v\not\in\operatorname{span} C$.  Now using  Gram-Schmidt (on a maximal linearly independent subset,  together with $\vec v$) one can get a nonzero vector $w\in(\operatorname{span}C)^{\bot}$.   Contradiction.

As to your proof,  it looks basically correct.

Comment: But if $\mathbf C$ is not linearly independent, we don't have $\mathbf C^\bot = \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Is that so?  Why?  I didn't catch that.

Comment: My mistake,  $C$ only has $n$ vectors...

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine but as it is enough to show that $\mathbf C $ is independent, then the result is immediate because if $\mathbf C $ is not independent, then the vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\dots ,v_n \}$ do not span $\mathbb R^n$ so we can pick $0\neq w\notin \text{span}\mathbf C$ and  observe that $0\neq w-\text{proj}_{\text{span}\mathbf C}w\in \mathbf C^{\perp.}$